# How do you calculate accuracy metric for a regression problem with multiple outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network

My CNN (Conv1D) on pytorch has 20 inputs and 6 outputs. The predicted output is said to be "accurate" only of all 6 them match,right? So, unless all my predicted results are accurate to the 8th decimal point ,will I ever be able to get decent accuracy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard accuracy metric is used for classification tasks. In order to sue accuracy you have to say if an output if one of the following: True positive (TP), True Negative (TN), False positive (FP), False negative (FN).

These classification metrics and be used to a certain extentin regression tasks, when you can apply these labels (TP, TN, FP, FN) to the outputs, maybe via simple threshold. This heavily depends on the kind of problem you are dealing with and may or may not be possible or useful.

As Andrey said in general you wan't to use metrics like the [Mean absolute error (MAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) or the [Mean squared error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error). But these metrics can be hard to interpret. I would suggest to look into papers who have a similar problem as you do and see which metrics they use to evaluate their results and compare themselves to other work.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! How do i determine what loss is good enough for my model. If the loss can be still improved , which I'm assuming can be done my changing the number of layers or the parameters , how do i move towards that sweet spot that would give me the best results other than Trial and Error. I know what I am asking is very vague but I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: You have to differentiate between loss and an evaluation metric. Loss is e.g. the MSE (L2 loss). The loss is used for training, the goal of the training is to minimize the loss. An evaluation metric normally tries to be more interpretable and more importantly comparable between different models, which solve the same task. To find the best model you basically just have to try and see but it can help to have a look at what other people did and use their experience. You often don't have to or want to come up with some architecture completely on your own

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy isn't a suitable metric for regression tasks. For regression tasks you should use such metrics as MAE, RMSE and so on.